# How to disable a HTML button from php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable a submit button when I get some trigger from the database that tells me I should disable it, I added some code in the echo line in PHP but it didn't work, what am I doing wrong?

**PHP CODE**

```
$tries= CCL::Triescount($userip)->NumofTries;
                if ($tries > 2 ) //Check wheter they have tried more than 2 times then block them
                {
                    $msg = "More than 2 attempts, block user";
                    echo '<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />';
                }
                else
                {
                     $tries++;
                     $msg = "Less than 2 attempts";
                     CCL::Updatetries($userip,$tries,0);
                     //insert into the DB

                }
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<div class="ui-body ui-body-c ui-corner-all">
    <h1>Forgot Password</h1>
    <form>

        <label for="emailpassdlbl"> Please enter the e-mail associated with your account, and a new auto-generated password will be sent to this e-mail account.</label>
        <input type="text" id="email"><BR>

        <div class="right">
            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <div data-role="popup" class="ui-body ui-body-c ui-corner-all">
        <h2 id="result"></h2>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="$(this).closest(\'[data-role=popup]\').popup(\'close\');" class="right">OK</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP being used?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this. Just as a note I didn't paste the whole PHP code, just pasted the part where I want to disable the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're changing the entire code with PHP to disable it, why not remove the submit functionality altogether?

For example:

```
 if ($tries > 2 ) //Check wheter they have tried more than 2 times then block them
                {
                    $msg = "More than 2 attempts, block user";
                    echo '<button type="button" disabled" />';
                }
```

As you can see we have actually removed the `type="submit"` and replaced it with `type="button"` it should still look like the same button however it wont submit the form (in addition to the disabled attribute).